# Rails 4 Jquery File Upload ProcessQueue Error with Resize Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am trying to upload multiple size versions of a single file directly to AWS S3 with the Jquery File Upload gem.

This code uploads correctly the file passed to the input:

```
$('#file_upload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
  var fileInput    = $(elem);
  var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
  fileInput.fileupload({
    fileInput:       fileInput,
    url:             form.data('url'),
    type:            'POST',
    autoUpload:       true,
    formData:         form.data('form-data'),
    paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
    dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
    replaceFileInput: false,
    disableImageResize: false,
    singleFileUploads: false,
    sequentialUploads: true,
    imageCrop: true,
    processQueue: [
          {
              action: 'loadImage',
              fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
              maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
          },
          {
              action: 'resizeImage',
              maxWidth: 400,
              maxHeight: 400
          },
          {action: 'saveImage'}
      ],
      processstart: function (e) {
          console.log('Processing started...');
      },
      process: function (e, data) {
          console.log('Processing ' + data.files[data.index].name + '...');
      },
      processdone: function (e, data) {
          console.log('Processing ' + data.files[data.index].name + ' done.');
      }
  }); //fileupload
```

I also want to upload the same image but resized to 200x200.
I followed the gem documentation https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-multiple-resolutions-of-one-image-with-multiple-resize-options and wrote the following processQueue

```
processQueue: [
          {
              action: 'loadImage',
              fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jpeg|png)$/,
              maxFileSize: 20000000 // 20MB
          },
          {
              action: 'resizeImage',
              maxWidth: 400,
              maxHeight: 400
          },
          {action: 'saveImage'},
          {action: 'duplicateImage'},
          {
              action: 'resizeImage',
              maxWidth: 200,
              maxHeight: 200
          },
          {action: 'saveImage'},
      ],
```

and added the duplicateImage action.

```
$.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.processActions.duplicateImage = function (data, options) {
  if (data.canvas) {
    data.files.push(data.files[data.index]);
  }
  return data;
};
```

**Problem :** the first **saveImage** does not upload the first image before duplicating. Instead there is only one POST request issued for both files, which returns the error **POST requires exactly one file upload per request.**

Is there a way to process the files one after the other?

Any idea what I'm missing?